# help needed for making a calendar like MS Outlook?

Tags: layout, calendar

i am doing work on an app like MS Outlook Calender where user can put events etc.
i am having problem with event object layout according to size etc. as user can drag and re size the event object in MS outlook calender and the size of event objects sets automatically.

i need the algorithm for doing so i have write my own but there are several problems help needed.

this screen shot will show the event object arrangement that is dynamic.[image]

Comment: What are you using to build your calendar app? (HTML+JS, WPF, etc.)

Comment: i am using flex action script

Comment: can any on describe the algo step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the ans

you can go for rectangle packing algorithm but keep in mind the events should be sorted w.r.t time and date and only horizontal packing will work for you

here is the rectangle packing [algo](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/36005/0/page/3)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Flex, this isn't a direct answer to your question, but it will hopefully set you down the right path.

Try taking a look at how [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)'s week and day views implement this.  FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin that renders a calendar which does exactly what you're looking for.

You'll have to extract the rendering logic from FullCalendar and translate it to your project in Flex.  I know JavaScript and ActionScript are very similar, but I've never used Flex — sorry I can't be more help in that area.

FullCalendar's repo is [here](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar).  Specifically, it looks like [AgendaView.js](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/agenda/AgendaView.js) is the most interesting file for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about a general **object layout algorithm**, right?

I am quite sure that this is a NP-complete problem: Arrange a set if *intervals*, each defined by a *start* and *end* as few *columns* as possible.

Being NP-complete means, that your best shot is probably trying out all possible arrangements:

- find *clusters* in your objects -- the *groups* where you have something to do, where intervals do overlap.
- for each cluster do

  - let *n* be the number of objects in the cluster
  - if *n* is too high (like 10 or 15), stop and just draw overlapping objects
  - generate all possible **orderings** of the objects in the cluster (for *n* objects, these are *n!* possible combinations, i.e. 6 objects, 120 possible orderings)
  - for each ordering lay out the objects in a trivial manner: loop through the elements and place them in an existing column if it fits there, start a new column if you need one.
  - keep the layout with the least columns

Comment: i have done this earlier but after some iterations of resizing it fail to layout all event boxes as needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

1. Events are packet into columns variable by day (or some other rule)
2. Events in one column are further separated into columns, as long as there is a continuous intersection on the Y-axis.
3. Events are assigned their X-axis value (0 to 1) and their X-size (0 to 1)
4. Events are recursively expanded, until the last of each intersectioned group (by Y and X axis) hits the column barrier or another event, that has finished expanding.

Essentially it is a brute force, but works fairly quickly, since there are not many events that need further expanding beyond step 3.

```
var physics = [];
var step = 0.01;

var PackEvents = function(columns){
    var n = columns.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var col = columns[ i ];
        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++)
        {
            var bubble = col[j];
            bubble.w = 1/n;
            bubble.x = i*bubble.w;
        }
    }
};

var collidesWith = function(a,b){
    return b.y < a.y+a.h && b.y+b.h > a.y;
};

var intersects = function(a,b){
    return b.x < a.x+a.w && b.x+b.w > a.x &&
           b.y < a.y+a.h && b.y+b.h > a.y;
};

var getIntersections = function(box){
    var i = [];
    Ext.each(physics,function(b){
        if(intersects(box,b) && b.x > box.x)
            i.push(b);
    });
    return i;
};

var expand = function(box,off,exp){
    var newBox = {
        x:box.x,
        y:box.y,
        w:box.w,
        h:box.h,
        collision:box.collision,
        rec:box.rec
    };
    newBox.x += off;
    newBox.w += exp;
    var i = getIntersections(newBox);
    var collision = newBox.x + newBox.w > 1;
    Ext.each(i,function(n){
        collision = collision || expand(n,off+step,step) || n.collision;
    });
    if(!collision){
        box.x = newBox.x;
        box.w = newBox.w;
        box.rec.x = box.x;
        box.rec.w = box.w;
    }else{
        box.collision = true;
    }
    return collision;
};

Ext.each(columns,function(column){
    var lastEventEnding = null;
    var columns = [];
    physics = [];

    Ext.each(column,function(a){
        if (lastEventEnding !== null && a.y >= lastEventEnding) {
            PackEvents(columns);
            columns = [];
            lastEventEnding = null;
        }
        var placed = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            var col = columns[ i ];
            if (!collidesWith( col[col.length-1], a ) ) {
                col.push(a);
                placed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!placed) {
            columns.push([a]);
        }
        if (lastEventEnding === null || a.y+a.h > lastEventEnding) {
            lastEventEnding = a.y+a.h;
        }
    });
    if (columns.length > 0) {
        PackEvents(columns);
    }

    Ext.each(column,function(a){
        a.box = {
            x:a.x,
            y:a.y,
            w:a.w,
            h:a.h,
            collision:false,
            rec:a
        };
        physics.push(a.box);
    });

    while(true){
        var box = null;
        for(i = 0; i < physics.length; i++){
            if(!physics[i].collision){
                box = physics[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if(box === null)
            break;
        expand(box,0,step);
    }

});
```

Result: http://imageshack.com/a/img913/9525/NbIqWK.jpg